# Replacing elements in a list, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How a value in a list can be replaced?

Suppose I have the following list :

`mylist=[1,3,5,7,4]`

and I just want to change the value at index 3 ( which would be 7) with, let's say, 9. (the change is not conditioned )

For earlier versions of python the replace function would work, but how do I do it in Python 3.6?

Comment: `mylist[3] = 9`?

Comment: I've been getting errors with that

Comment: What errors? Edit the question to show the message you get.

Comment: Actually it worked , there was something else wrong, thanks

Comment: @Alex12 on what version of Python did `list` have a `replace` method?

Comment: on 2.7? I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console:

```
➜ ~ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug 03 2017, 16:34:42) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mylist=[1,3,5,7,4]
>>> mylist[3]=9
>>> mylist
[1, 3, 5, 9, 4]
>>>
```

Just like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> mylist = [1,3,5,7,4]
```

1 . The simplest, go to the list `index` and assign it the new value.

```
>>> mylist[3] = 9
>>> mylist
=> [1, 3, 5, 9, 4]
```

2 . `Slicing`

```
>>> mylist = mylist[:3] + [9] + mylist[4:]
>>> mylist
=> [1, 3, 5, 9, 4]
```

Comment: @Alex12 : Sure. Glad to help