# Replacing element in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. I want to replace `J[0][0]` with `Leftover[0]`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
Leftover = [1]
J = [[0, 0, 7, 9, 10]]

for i in range(len(J)):
    J[0][Leftover[0]] = 1

print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[[0, 1, 7, 9, 10]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1,0,7,9,10]]
```

Comment: `J[0][0] = Leftover[0]`? and why do you have a loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing elements in a list, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872550/replacing-elements-in-a-list-python)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a loop for doing this :)

```
Leftover = [1]
J = [[0, 0, 7, 9, 10]]

J[0][0] = Leftover[0]
```